# Spring Boot @Autowired in unit test returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, resttemplate

I have a class(HttpHandler) annotated with @service. I'm writing unit test case for this service class.
I used @Autowired annotation in my test class to get the object of the service. However, When I run the unit test it return NullPOinterException. Can someone help me?

Below is the code of service class:

```
@Service
public class HttpHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpHandler.class);

    /**
     * Build the request and Perform Http Get request with headers
     * @param url
     * @param httpHeaders
     * @param responseClass
     * @param <T>
     * @param <R>
     * @return
     */
    public <T,R> ResponseEntity<T> sendPost(String url, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, R requestBody, Class<T> responseClass) {
        //create an instance of rest template
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<R> entity = new HttpEntity<R>(requestBody, httpHeaders);
        logger.info("POST request to " + url + " with body: " + JsonUtil.jsonizeExcludeNulls(requestBody));
        //make an HTTP POST request with headers
        ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, responseClass);
        logger.info("POST" + url + ": " + JsonUtil.jsonize(response));
        return response;
    }
}
```

I'm writing unit test case for POST call. Below is the unit test for POST call
public class HttpHandlerTest {

```
@Autowired
HttpHandler httpHandler;

@Test
public void testSuccessPostUser() throws Exception{

    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/users";
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    messages.add("Hi");

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(1);
    user.setName("John");
    user.setAge(22);
    user.setMessages(messages);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    HttpEntity<User> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(user, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<User> actual = httpHandler.sendPost(baseUrl, httpHeaders, user, User.class);

    //verify request succeed
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, actual.getStatusCode());
    assertEquals(201, actual.getStatusCodeValue());
    assertTrue(actual.toString().contains("id"));
}
```

}

It gives below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xyz.provisioning.xyz.utils.HttpHandlerTest.testSuccessPostUser(HttpHandlerTest.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
```

Comment: Do you have ApplicationTest main class?

Comment: @silentsudo, Yes I have Here is the code ```@SpringBootTest
class XYZApplicationTests {

 @Test
 void contextLoads() {
 }

}```

Comment: But you don't have `@SpringBootTest` _on your `HttpHandlerTest`_.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I defined ```@SpringBootTestDo``` on HttpHandlerTest class and it worked!!! Do I need to define ```@SpringBootTest``` on every unit test class?

Comment: you are hitting sendPost, your class doesn't have this method!

Comment: sorry for the typo mistake! Have made the changes for hitting sendPost call. Also, After adding @springBootTest annotation on HttpHandler class it does not give me NullPointerException.

Comment: since it, resolved your issue, you can answer this question now mentioning chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic's as reference answer!

Comment: Is it compulsory to add '@SpringBootTest' annotation whenever @Autowired is used?

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` loads the full Spring context. If you just want to test your service you can use `Mockito`.

Comment: @marc we use Mockito for integration testing right?

Comment: You use Mockito any time you want to replace one of your objects (works best with interfaces and constructor injection) with a test placeholder. You can do this in full-application testing to replace external services, but it's most common in unit tests, where you replace everything except the class you're actively testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Junit 5 (as mentioned in the comments) you just need to add `@SpringBootTest` on top of the test class.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class HttpHandlerTest{
// ...
}
```

**You don't need** to add `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` because is automatically imported by the annotation `@SpringBootTest`.

To get the same result for Junit 4:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class HttpHandlerTest{
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` above the class if you're using JUnit5 or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` if you're using JUnit4.

Comment: Hoe does ```@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)``` makes a difference ass compare to ```@SpringBootTest``` and ```Mockito```?

Comment: Using Junit5 you don't need to add `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` because is automatically imported by the annotation `@SpringBootTest`.