# Autowired class is null in TestClassMockito

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

MyTestClass

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CartServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private CartRepository cartRepository;
    @Mock
    private CartItemRepository cartItemRepository;
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Mock
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Mock
    private UserService userService;
    @InjectMocks
    private CartService cartService;

    @Test
    void checkedClearCartFromAllItems(){
        Principal principal = mock(Principal.class);
        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(userService.getUserOfPrincipal(principal)).thenReturn(user);

        cartService.clearCart(principal);
    }
```

the class I'm testing

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CartService {
    private final CartRepository cartRepository;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final CartItemRepository cartItemRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
```

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "onlineshop.shop.service.UserService.getUserOfPrincipal(java.security.Principal)" because "this.userService" is null`

I want to test method in CartService because i need use method in userService,userService autowired in Cartservice. When I run test I get Exception "userService is null" but if I userService add in constructor in CartService all works.
I am just interesting can I do test with autowired userService in CartService or not

Comment: It's possible(https://stackoverflow.com/a/63188114/19875155), but not recommended.
Please consider using "@WithMockUser" in the answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920932/19875155

Comment: do you have getter / setter defined for userService object in cartService class ?

Comment: @Vihar I dont have .It so important ?

Comment: try adding and check if that solves your issue

Comment: Why are you mixing constructor and field injection?

Comment: @tgdavies maybe this is funny, but I heard somewhere that services should not be final

Comment: The problem is the mix of constructor and field injection, which isn't supported by Mockito. It will then prefer the constructor injection and do nothing for the field. Either do everything with field injection or do everything with constructor injection (preferred).

Comment: That's completely false. All fields should be final unless there is a very good reason to make them mutable (if Java was designed today I expect that fields would be final by default)

Answer (score -1):

Mockito doesn't know anything about the autowiring, to do it properly you need to start the spring framework and load the `CartService` as a spring bean.
Now this will mean that your test won't be a unit test anymore (unit tests are meant to be really fast and certainly they shouldn't use spring)

If you still want to work only with Mockito, don't use field injection (this is a term for the technique you've used: putting `@Autowired` on the internal field)

Instead consider using the Constructor Injection

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CartService {
    private final CartRepository cartRepository;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final CartItemRepository cartItemRepository;
    private final UserService userService;
    ...
}
```

Now you can create `UserService` with `@Mock` annotation in the test.

This way the class can be tested without Spring only with mockito, this will be the unit test. I personally always prefer this way of injection whenever I can exactly because of this reason - I can test it easily.

Comment: Thanks.Is it normal practice to make the service final?

Comment: Yes mockito doesn't know about `@Autowired` but still it can do field injection and it doesn't care about the `@Autowired` then. The problem here is is the mix of Constructor and field injection, which Mockito doesn't support. It will then pick constructor injection and do nothing about the fields. Making it do constructor injection is indeed going to solve it. But your reasoning about field injection not working for Mockito is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

you can even set autowired field value using ReflectionTestUtils. If you'll do this way value will not be null and you'll get your mocked Value.
Eg:-

ReflectionTestUtils.setField(cartService, "userService", userServiceMock);
Here, cartService is your class object which you're testing.
userService is the autowired object which you're trying to set.
userServiceMock is the mocked object of UserService.

your test-case will look like this-

```
@Test
    void checkedClearCartFromAllItems(){
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(cartService, "userService", userService);
        Principal principal = mock(Principal.class);
        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(userService.getUserOfPrincipal(principal)).thenReturn(user);

        cartService.clearCart(principal);
    }
```